# Insert elements in several positions in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

How to insert multiple elements in a list?

> `list={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}`
>
> Output: `{"X" 1,"X" 2,"X" 3,"X" 4,"X" 5,"X" 6,"X" 7,"X" 8,"X" 9}`

I have the `list`and would like to insert a string `X` into each element in the list. How do I do that?

Comment: How about "X" # & /@ list

Comment: Sorry for nitpicking: `HoldForm /@ {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9} "X"`

Comment: Just to add one more way: `list /. x_Integer -> {"X", x} // Flatten ` ??

Comment: Dear NewTester4201, are missing comas intentional?

Comment: Is it a good example of 'easy found in [doc](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Riffle.html)'?

Comment: Is this question about formatting output? Or is about generating a list that will used in further computation?

Comment: How about `For[i = 1, i <= Length[list], i++,
  list[[i]] = Row[{"X ", list[[i]]}]
  ];`?